# How do I get started as an online math tutor?

Tags: tutoring, online

I have a master in math, teaching experience as a graduate student, TA experience and tons of in-person tutoring. I feel like a pretty prime candidate to be an online tutor. Can anyone give me some advice on how to get started? Thanks!

Comment: Make a website. Follow groups that use methods you like.

Comment: You can join an existing on-line organization that offers that service.  They will handle things like collecting money from the clients and paying you.  But beware: some sites are really about "cheat on your homework/exam/writing".

Answer (score 3):

I have much fewer qualifications and I see myself as a fine tutor, so no doubt you are even more justified in your belief.

There are various websites that allow tutors to set up a profile, post details and rates, but allow the tutors to interact directly with the clients. Many these sites either charge to client or far more commonly charge the tutors, typically for a first-contact. I don't want to give specific names as the one I used, and such sites in general, was susceptible to false information or even scams. I joined one with a low bar of entry and I'm sure with a Masters you can join more selective ones.

If you join an online community of students you are looking to tutor, you may be occasionally allowed to advertise your services. This depends on the nature and type of the student community. This is more to build reputation than to gain leads per se.

This is more true for high school, but you also want to contact the parent or whoever is paying for the services, and high schoolers and undergrads aren't willing to pay as much. Unless you want to tutor some international program or competition, most parents want a local tutor so you should seek to advertise locally, even if you meet online. Along these lines, see if you can be allowed to advertise on campus or even be listed as a tutor.

For international programs or competitions, it's best to open a website and do some SEO. The technical details should refer to stackexchange or the alike.

Comment: (+1) for many suggestions. For what it's worth, when I was in college, bulletin boards near classrooms where math courses were taught (especially lower level classes) tended to be papered over with tutor advertisements (usually a catchy looking sheet of paper with pull-off tabs for phone number contact at the bottom). In fact, I did this myself many times. Fast-forward about 30 years (13 years ago), I found myself similarly needing money, so I got myself on some locally distributed tutor lists and tutored a lot of local HS and college students for 4-5 years outside of my job (non-academic).